# Docker image for Nodejs and Couchbase SDK

Tags: node.js, docker, couchbase, alpine-linux, musl

So we have a nodejs micro-service using the NodeJS Couchbase [SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/couchbase/v/3.2.1) 3.2
We are trying to build a minimal docker image for our App using the Alpine base image but it seems the sdk needs more than what we have added to our base image.

Here is our dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-alpine3.13

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp python3 make g++

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

COPY .npmrc ./

RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN npm install --only=production

RUN rm -rf .gyp

COPY . .

CMD [ “npm”, “start”]
```

We run into the following error,

```
Error: Error loading shared library libresolv.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /app/node_modules/couchbase/build/Release/couchbase_impl.node)
at Object.Module._extensions…node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1187:18)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
at Object.bindings [as default] (/app/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
at Object. (/app/node_modules/couchbase/dist/binding.js:70:35)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
at Object.Module._extensions…js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
```

Is there any extra alpine lib we need to add ?

EDIT: This issue seems to be deeper than I thought.
Refer to this thread : [Use shared library that uses glibc on AlpineLinux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70243938/use-shared-library-that-uses-glibc-on-alpinelinux)

So it says Alpine uses musl as a c lib and apparently couchbase needs glibc ?

**EDIT 2: This now works.**

```
FROM node:12-alpine3.13
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp python3 make g++
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY .npmrc ./
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g node-gyp
RUN npm install couchbase
RUN rm -rf .gyp
COPY . .
CMD [ “npm”, “start”]
```

Comment: If you're starting to run into problems around "which libc do I actually have" then it will be easier and not substantially larger to use a Debian- or Ubuntu-based image instead of Alpine.

Comment: While I agree that a debian image such as node:buster would solve my problem, but a larger image comes with a lot of vulnerabilities. Alpine seems to have the least.

Comment: _So it says Alpine uses musl as a c lib_ > yes it is, and that's what makes it light. Sadly, you are in a situation where Alpine is not a solution. Use `node:12-bullseye-slim`, rather, it also comes with less fluff installed (hence the name `slim`), so your are nearly on the same ground as with Alpine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered on the Couchbase forums: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/help-docker-image-for-nodejs-app-using-couchbase-sdk-3-2/33267

In short, Alpine is not officially supported. You can read more information on [platform compatibility in the documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/nodejs-sdk/3.2/project-docs/compatibility.html#platform-compatibility). There you can find a supported distro that works well for your needs.

As was shared on the forums, the option `--build-with-source` will avoid using prebuilds, which may provide an adequate workaround for building on Alpine but its important to note that this is not the same as an officially supported platform.

Feel free to follow up with any additional questions or concerns!